# Presentation for a fact in past

Tags: tense

Can you help me to determine which type of sentence that I should use in this situation?

I and my colleague attended a job on 8th September 2015 for promotion of new goods. At that time, we discussed and had an agreement that he would write the report, that meant his report would also cover my part.

Today, my company asked me about my report and my response will be as follows:

> I discussed with Peter for the report writing, he agreed that he will write report and I write the log only

Is it okay if I write it as above?

Comment: I discussed writing the report with Peter,  who agreed that he would write it and I would write its log.

Answer (score 1):

As written, *i discussed with Peter for the report writing, he agreed that he will write report and i write the log only*, there are several problems.  A bit of reconstruction to make the meaning clear is in order.

> Peter and I discussed the writing of the report, and we agreed that he will write the report and I will write the log

or rewritten in two sentences, for example:

> Peter and I discussed writing the report.  We agreed that he will write the report, and I will write the log.

The phrase *for the*, as used in the original construction, sounds stilted after the prepositional phrase *with Peter* and confuses the meaning of two people having a discussion about writing a report.  In the second clause, did the subject *I* agree to this division of labor?  If not, then there is no agreement from the discussion.  If Peter decided that he would write the report and not the log, then the verb *decided* would be a better choice.  Also, perhaps it was a typo, but an article is needed to denote the thing before *report* (i.e., *the report*).

Since this is something that has already been done, future verb tense should be *would* instead of *will* in the second clause.

Answer (score 0):

You had an agreement with Peter in the recent **past**, September 2015. You are being asked about the report in October, which is the **present**. Keeping the **past** and **present** tense rules in mind, this is how you can construct your statement:

> I had discussed with Peter about the report writing and he had agreed
>   that he would write the report and I was to write only the log.

Note how the words of the past tense are inserted to emphasize that the discussion and agreement of *who would do what* was done in the past.